# problem with operator[] when trying to access a vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I have the following class :

```
class Character
{
     /unimportant code
}
class Fighter : public Character
{
     /unimportant code
}
class Healer: public Character
{
     /unimportant code
}


class Game
{
public:
    void move(const GridPoint & src_coordinates,  const GridPoint & dst_coordinates);
    //there are more things here ,but they're not important for the sake of this question. 
private:
    int height;
    int width;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> gameboard;
};


void move(const GridPoint & src_coordinates,  const GridPoint & dst_coordinates)
{
    for (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator i = gameboard.begin(); i != 
                                                                  gameboard.end() ; i++ )
    {
        if ( (*gameboard[i]).coordinates == src_coordinates)
        {
            //do I need to implement my own [] operator?
        }
           
        
    }
        
}
```

Im trying to iterate over my gameboard and move the character from src_coordinates to dst_coordinates. Character is also a class that's inherited by a few more :

I get the following error when I try to access the elements of gameboard[i] :

```
no match for 'operator[] (operand types are 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character> >' and 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character> >::iterator' {aka '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Character>*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character> > >'}
```

does that mean that I have to implement my own operator[] and operator* because Character is a class of my own? and how can I solve my ptoblem?

Comment: You use `operator[]` with index, when you have iterator you just dereference it like a pointer. So in your case it would be (*i)->coordinates

Comment: So, you have a container called `gameboard` and an iterator called `i` that iterates over that container. The way you get the underlying elements from your container is not `*gameboard[i]`. It is... wait for it... `*i`. Just as you would if your container were a plain array, and your iterator were a pointer.

Comment: A vector can be accessed like an array with indexes using the`[]` operator. Or using iterators. But an iterator is *not* an index. It kind of seems like you skipped some parts of your text-book or tutorial or class. Besides, I suggest you learn about [the range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), where you need neither indexes nor iterators. As in `for (auto const& character_pointer : gameboard)`

Comment: The vector already implements `operator[]`. You would not be able to implement one if it didn't (because you don't have access to the internals). Plus you don't need it anyway. Implementing `operator[]` for the `Character` makes no sense, because `Character` isn't a container.

Comment: `for (auto &gb: gameboard)` would be much more idiomatic.

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong, but you could write your iterator loop in a more clean way using a range based for loop.   for(const auto& field : gameboard), field will enumerate over all available shared_ptr's by const reference.

Comment: @KenY-N I concur, but const auto& would be more precise if you're not going to change the shared_ptr's :)

Comment: @PKramer I had `const` at first, but the method name `move()` implies the character's coordinates may change so I deleted it.

Comment: @KenY-N Good point, a move must indeed be able to change the content of gameboard :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators are a generalization of pointers. You use `*` to get the pointed-at thing from a pointer; you use `*` to get the element of a container that an iterator is currently "pointing at". The iterator type uses operator overloading so that it can behave like a pointer, even when the underlying container isn't a simple array.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator
```

This **means**: "a thing that, when you apply `*` to it, gives you a `std::shared_ptr<Character>` that came from a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>` (among other useful properties)".

Each time through the loop, `*i` is one of the `std::shared_ptr<Character>`s in the vector. Therefore, `(*i)->coordinates` are the coordinates of the `Character` that the `shared_ptr` points at. (Notice `->`, because we also have to dereference the `shared_ptr`.)

> no match for 'operator[]

This happens because you are trying to use the iterator as if it were an index. You can clearly see what is wrong with the following code:

```
char[] example = "hello, world\n";
char* ptr = &example[0];
example[ptr]; // wait, what?
```